# Creating a model with a time attribute in Sails from Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, validationerror

I am running sails as the back end for an angular project. I am trying to create an object in my database which has a date and time. The date is working fine using the input[date] and passing that as a date object to the create call. I tried to do the same thing with time using input[time], but it seems that this input also creates a date object which is not what the sails model expects.

I have tried getting it to store as both a date and time type both which give me validation errors. If I change the attribute type to string though, everything works fine, but the time is stored in military format, but I'd rather have it as a time I can format in angular. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried getting it to store as both a date and time type both
>   which give me validation errors.

There is an issue on this https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/966

Use DATETIME instead of TIME. Then you read just time hours/minutes/seconds from it.

> but the time is stored in military format, but I'd rather have it as a
>   time I can format in angular.

DATETIME will store the date+time in Zulu timezone. When you use the correct locale in angular it will convert it to local time automatically. You also can use [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/)